# Should I change a family environment workplace for another one?

Tags: employer-relations, hiring, dismissal

I've been working full-time for over 3 years in a company while if I'd have to count even the
scholastic internship's done during my hight school, I'm in that company 6 years.

I'm 21 and my role in that company is a Full-Stack developer.

During the years of work, I've learned to program with different programming languages and frameworks and when there is some new work to do even the senior developer comes to me to asks advices on how it should be done.

The company has a very friendly environment and if I have to take a day off, they'll have no problem with it and stuff like this.

The issue is that in all that years I've taken the minimum pay for my work and after I've talked about that with my head he told me to wait as in September my apprenticeship will end and my contract will change and as he said "the company usually doesn't increase the pay but when the contract is changed it will go to the moon" but idk how that moon will be.

At the same time, every day I receive lot of work requests in LinkedIn to which I never responded as I would feel like a traitor in comparison to the company.

But yesterday, I tried to answer to some of that proposal and I've immediately received all details about the jobs and all of them would offer me a better professional environment and the pay would be almost the double of what I'm taking...

The issue is that should I wait for the change of the contract to see what my actual company is going to offer to me?

What should I do?

I'm so confused...

Comment: Each of us has to decide whether the flexibility and atmosphere of a company is worth getting paid less than the maximum, or if we want to put up with a lot of stress for high pay. If your company hasn't broken promises to increase your pay, it may be worth seeing what their plans are. And if you look for jobs, you may find another that has flexibility AND higher pay. Prioritizing these things is up to you.

Comment: @JohnK, You have worked for that company full-time for 3 years, and still get the minimum salary. I suppose it is OK to have some interviews with other companies to see how everything goes. After you pass the interviews, and after other companies send you the job offers, it will be easier to compare and make the decision.

Comment: It's a common mistake for a young developer to hang onto misplaced "loyalty" to their first company, when the business world doesn't really honor any such thing.

Comment: You should always go to interviews, for so may reasons. 1: Free interview practice. 2: Market research. You’re worth what somebody is willing to pay for you. How much is that? The only way to find out is to actually get an offer somewhere else. 3: You never know what other amazing companies might be out there. Taking an interview doesn’t commit you to anything. You can still turn down any offer you get. 4: It builds your network and gives you connections at other companies. And I can go on and on. Bottom line is: Take the goddamned interviews.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you **should** do depends on you, but let me tell my thoughts which are quite a constrast to the first answer that was given.

Your apprentice payment can't be compared to normal salary at all. This seems to change for you in a few weeks.
If you really like your current job with all that is around and it's only about payment, isn't it the worst moment to give up now as you are so close to see what you get in a normal contract?

Answer (score -5):

- in all that years I've taken the minimum pay

Disgusting

- the company usually doesn't increase the pay

Disgusting lie

- your! salary! will! go! to! the! moon!

The most disgusting lie in business.  They should ***state a figure*** or stop lying.

Walk away today. Never have anything to do with them again ever.

> But yesterday i tried to answer to some of that proposal and i've immediatly received all details about the jobs and all of them would offer me a better professional environment and the pay would be almost the double of what i'm taking...

**Immediately, instantly, accept and secure one of these new offers.**

Comment: What's the reasoning here? Why not wait and see what OP's current company intends to offer when their contract changes? Why "never have anything to do with them ever again"? Sounds like unnecessary bridge burning to me....

Comment: Are you trolling here? This is unreasonable and extreme given the facts shared by the OP

Comment: @Anthony , I already responded to some comments, but they seem to have been deleted, so - that's that.  Cheers

Comment: @Anthony Look at other answers Fattie has posted.  They're frequently opinionated to the point of provocativeness; and even when IMO the core point being presented is reasonable end up taking large numbers of down votes due to how they're presented.

Comment: Dunno what to say. the idiotic lie "HONEST, WE'RE REALLY GOING TO PAY YOU A LOT! SOON!  CANT MENTION HOW MUCH!  BUT A LOT" is astoundingly puerile. It's the most basic lie in the workplace.  RUN AWAY.